# Is it possible to repeat a specific operation twice but only on Mondays?

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with the below macro.

I run a macro for my report on a daily basis. But only on Mondays, I need to repeat the below operations two times more(3 times altogether):

```
Range("B8").End(xlToRight).Offset(, 0).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Range("B9").End(xlToRight).Offset(, 0).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I'm guessing that I need to use the `Weekday(Now()) = vbMonday` statement but not 100% sure how to use it with the above code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thanks for advice Pᴇʜ, I will do so, just need to find a bit of spare time within the next few days :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do it. The first one is to make it a separate `Sub` and to call it explicitly 3 times on Monday.

```
Sub TestMe()

    If Weekday(Now()) = vbMonday Then
        SomeSelection
        SomeSelection
        SomeSelection
    End If

End Sub

Sub SomeSelection()
    'OP Code
End Sub
```

The second one is to make a loop and to make sure it repeats 3 times on Monday:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim repeater As Long: repeater = 1
    If Weekday(Now()) = vbMonday Then repeater = 3

    Dim counter As Long
    For counter = 1 To repeater
        Range("B8").End(xlToRight).Offset(, 0).Select
        'OP code...
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I made a loop as advised above and it works perfectly. Thanks Vityata

Comment: @SeT - welcome. As a next step, try to refactor the whole code, avoiding select, as mentioned in the comment in the question - it would be of use, if you invest a few hours trying to do it - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Thanks Vityata, will definitely recreate my code within the next few days, just need to find a bit of spare time to do so :)